# Uncaught Typeerror obj2.getName is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

```
const obj = {
    name: "John",
    getName: function() {
        return  this.name
              
    }
}

console.log("Type", typeof(obj.getName())) 

const obj2 = {
    roll: 2,
    desig: "Software developer",
    name : "Peter",
    _proto_: obj 

}
console.log(obj2.getName())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__proto__` with two underscores on each side, not one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `__proto__` not `_proto_`